# Drink Vending Machine Code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Hello Stackflow community,
I'm currently taking a class in Visual Basic and I'm in need of some assistance. I am creating a program that simulates a Drink Vending Machine using an array. The instructions follow:
Create an application that simulates a soft-drink vending machine. The application should let the user select one of the following soft drinks:

Cola ($1.00 each)
Root Beer ($1.00 each)
Lemon Lime Soda ($1.00 each)
Grape Soda ($1.50 each)
Cream Soda ($1.50 each)

When the application starts, the vending machine will have 20 of each type of soft drink. Each time the user selects a drink, the application should subtract 1 from the quantity of the selected drink. It should also update and display the total amount of sales. If the user selects a drink that is sold out, a message should be displayed indicating so.

In the application’s code, create a structure that has fields for the following data:

Drink name
Drink cost
Number of drinks in machine

The program should create an array of five structure objects. Each element of the array should keep data for a specific type of soft drink.

I can't figure out how to make my buttons work to decrement the quantity labels and then add each click to the label total. Please help.

```
Public Class Form1
' Class-level declarations
Const intMAX_SUBSCRIPT As Integer = 4               ' Upper subscript
Dim strProdNames(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT) As String        ' Product Names
Dim decPrice(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT) As Decimal           ' Drink Price
Dim intProdNums(intMAX_SUBSCRIPT) As Integer        ' Product Numbers

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Initialize the arrays with the product data.
    InitArrays()
End Sub

Private Sub InitArrays()
    ' Initialize the arrays.

    ' First Product
    strProdNames(0) = "Cola"
    decPrice(0) = 1D
    intProdNums(0) = 20

    ' Second Product
    strProdNames(1) = "Root Beer"
    decPrice(1) = 1D
    intProdNums(1) = 20

    ' Third Product
    strProdNames(2) = "Lemon Lime"
    decPrice(2) = 1D
    intProdNums(2) = 20

    ' Fourth Product
    strProdNames(3) = "Grape Soda"
    decPrice(3) = 1.5D
    intProdNums(3) = 20

    ' Fifth Product
    strProdNames(4) = "Cream Soda"
    decPrice(4) = 1.5D
    intProdNums(4) = 20

End Sub

Private Sub btnCola_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCola.Click
    Dim intCount As Integer = 20        ' Loop Counter

    intCount -= 1                       ' Decrement drink count

    If intCount > 0 Then
        lblTotal.Text = decPrice(0).ToString("c")
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrement the cola count, which is in the array.

```
 Private Sub btnCola_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If intProdNums(0) > 0 Then
            intProdNums(0)-=1  ' decrement cola drink count
        End If

        ' show results here...
    End Sub
```